# How to load a remote html file in Android WebView in Emulator which is behind a proxy

Tags: android, webview, proxy

Iam trying to load a remote html file in Android Webview in Emulator which is behind a Proxy.The same remote html file if i try to load in the Android Emulator Browser,it is loading fine without any problem.So Prior to this i made proxy settings in the Emulator using the below path.
 Settings->Wireless&Networks->Mobile Networks->Access Point Names->Telkila and then i configured my proxy,port,username and password.So that the Android Emulator Browser is able to use the proxy settings which i configured but not the Android application(.apk) which is running in the Emulator.Any help?.

Thanks in Advance.

Venkat.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your android activity onCreate()

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
            System.getProperties().put("proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
            System.getProperties().put("proxyPort", "8000");
```

Just put value of proxy host and port as per your case.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you are doing from your android application.Are you loading a WebView from activity or making HTTP call from it?

Comment: Iam loading WebView from "Activity".Any i got answer with the below code
 public void loadUrl(WebView view, String url, String proxyUserName, String proxyPassword){
        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds= new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUserName, proxyPassword);
        Header credHeader = BasicScheme.authenticate(creds, "UTF-8", true);
        Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
        header.put(credHeader.getName(), credHeader.getValue());
        view.loadUrl(url, header);
    }